# Moving rendered elements of a new html page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Javascript function I'm rendering on a page where the user can click on a list element and it will bring them to a new page showing more information about that list element. The original page is #index and the second page is #index2 which is coded using one multipage HTML page. 
However I am hoping that I can move the index2 page to its own html file - index2.html but I'm not sure how I can reference the new index.html file within the function so that the elements can move to the new file.

My code is as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){
        $("#list").empty();
        var url="http://localhost/tmp/json4.php";
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){
            //loop through deals
            $.each(json.deals,function(i,dat){
                $("#list").append("<li><a id='"+dat.dealid+"' data-restaurantid=" + dat.restaurantid + " data-image=" + dat.image + "><h1>"+dat.name+"</h1><h6>"+dat.dname+"</h6><h5>"+dat.description+"</h5></a></li>");
                $(document).on('click', '#'+dat.dealid, function(event){  
                    if(event.handled !== true) 
                    {
                        dealObject.dealID = $(this).attr('id'); 
                        dealObject.restaurantid = $(this).attr('data-restaurantid');
                        dealObject.shortName = $(this).find('h1').html(); 
                        dealObject.image = $(this).attr('data-image');
                        dealObject.dealName = $(this).find('h6').html();
                        dealObject.description = $(this).find('h5').html(); 

                        $.mobile.changePage( "#index2", { transition: "slide"} );
                        event.handled = true;
                    }
                });            
            });
            $("#list").listview('refresh');
        });
    });

    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index2', function(){       
        $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('#deal-img').attr('src',dealObject.dealObject);
        $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('#title').html(dealObject.name);
                $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('input#desc').val(dealObject.description);
                $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('input#tname').val(dealObject.dealName);
                $('#index2 [data-role="content"]').find('input#dealid').val(dealObject.dealID);


    });

    var dealObject = {
        dealID : null,
        restaurantid : null,
        shortName : null,
        image : null,
        dealName : null,
        description: null
    }    
</script>
```

If somebody could help me I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to separate pages into two php files, one called view.php and second one called offer.php.

Create 2 additional directories, one called amend and second one called del. Both of them will have a js file with logic related to the amend or delete functionality plus a php file which will server as a php/ajax proxy for a needed functionality.

Also take care that your 2 ajax calls must look at a correct location and that ajax response also must state witch action has beed done.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you will need to make an Ajax request to your server for index2.html, since it no longer lives on the same page as index1.html. Here's an example

```
$.ajax({
   url : '/pages/index2.html',
   type: 'get',
   success: function (html) {
     // here , you can use jquery to manipulate
     // the HTML in index2. Maybe pop up a lightbox, etc..
   }
});
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but Ajax is a fairly standard way of requesting new HTML / data behind the scenes. There is a lot you can do with JQuery ajax. Here are the docs

[Jquery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)